# Can anyone tell me why when I add a value in this part of my form it doesn't show up on the screen?

Tags: wordpress, forms, user-interface, frontend, gravity-forms-plugin

[This](http://www.yourcourttennis.com/shop/shop-2/schedule-an-appointment/) is the form that I am talking about. Everything works fine with the exception of the quantity option in the " Additional Student section. It works properly when I submit the form. It calculates whatever integer you place into the box, but It does not show up on the front end. Any help would be gladly appreciated. I tried to inspect it, but couldn't discover a solution.

P.S 
Not sure if it is pertinent, but I am using Gravity Forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the solution. The box width for the item was too short. I resized it and now you can view the entry.